# Create all Combinations Java

Tags: java, combinatorics

I want to create all combinations with two states(1 and 0).
If i do this with two for-loops, this works. But when I use a self-calling function it doesnt. Does anybody can tell me why, please ?

For-Loops :

```
public class Counter {
     public Counter() {
         loop(iter);
         for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
              for (int i2=0; i2 < 2; i2++) {
                   System.out.println(Integer.toString(i)+Integer.toString(i2));
              }
         }
     }
     public static void main(String args[]){
         new Counter();
     }
}
```

Self-Calling Function :

```
class Stringhelper {
    public Stringhelper() {
    }
    public String getstring(String string,int beginning,int ending) {
         if (string.length() != 0) {
         String newstring="";
         for (int iter=Math.abs(beginning); iter < ending && iter < string.length(); iter=iter+1) {
              newstring=newstring+Character.toString(string.charAt(iter));
         }
         return newstring;
         }
         else {
         return "";
         }
    }
}

public class Counter {
     public String abil="";
     public int iter=1;
     public Stringhelper shelper=new Stringhelper();
     public void loop(int iter) {
         for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
              abil=abil+Integer.toString(i);
              if (iter==0) {
                  System.out.println(abil);
                  abil=shelper.getstring(abil,0,abil.length()-1);
              }
              else {
                  loop(iter-1);
              }
         }
     }
     public Counter() {
         loop(iter);

     }
     public static void main(String args[]){
         new Counter();
     }
}
```

And using the self-calling Function the output is 00,01,010,011 instead of 00,01,10,11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explaining your code here (ignore abil for now):

```
public void loop(int iter) {
         for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
              abil=abil+Integer.toString(i);
              if (iter==0) {
                  System.out.println(abil);
                  abil=shelper.getstring(abil,0,abil.length()-1);
              }
              else {
                  loop(iter-1);
              }
         }
     }
```

When iter is 0 it will print it

In the next iteration, when it is not equal to 0, another loop is created, added to the stack, where it starts again from 0, and prints abil's new stack value.

When you create a new stack it recreates all the variables in temporary storage until the code exits. In this case it keeps creating stacks and never exits. In order to exit a stack, use return.

In summary, you need to learn more about how stacks and recursion work in order to fix your problem.

Comment: thanks, but can you please explain why the output is : 00,01,010,011 instead of : 00,01,10,11

Comment: Why not use the original for loop? Recursion should only be used in particular instances and this is most definitely not one of them. It is also slower than the original for loop. Also, make use of better naming conventions as, right now it is very difficult to read your code. 

The problem is somewhere in 
abil=shelper.getstring(abil,0,abil.length()-1);

but I as of right now, its extremely difficult to debug and other users seem to agree as you're being downvoted

Comment: So in summary: seperate different functions into separate methods, name the variables in an initiative way, and don't let lines get longer than 44 characters

Comment: When you post again let me know

Comment: thanks. the abil=shelper.getstring(abil,0,abil.length()-1); is for cutting the last char, because i dont want to have 00 and 001, but 00 and 01, so i cut the second char

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void loop(int iter) {
     for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
          if (i==1) {
              abil=shelper.getstring(abil,0,iter);
          }
          abil=abil+Integer.toString(i);
          if (iter==4) {
              System.out.println(abil);
          }
          else {
              loop(iter+1);
          }
     }
 }
```

this did the trick